# Кавычки, или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

В Аммане есть такая разновидность транспорта «общественное такси».

Answer (score 2):

**В Аммане – столице Иордании – есть необычный вид транспорта: общественное такси.** Выглядит оно так: на небольшой стоянке, а чаще просто у обочины стоят, дожидаясь пассажиров, две-три старенькие легковые машины. Когда пассажиры набиваются в автомобиль под завязку (пятеро худеньких или четверо толстеньких), машина начинает движение – но не куда вам вздумается, а по заранее известному маршруту. http://gazetarespublika.info/proexat-aziyu-poezda-avtobusy-marshrutki/

**Как мы видим, кваычек нет, так как в статье объяснено, как выглядит общественное такси.** А выглядеть оно может по-разному. С одной стороны, такси – это вид общественного транспора, с другой – **его особый вид.**

Например: **В Кирове планируют запустить общественное такси,** которое будет перевозить пассажиров по определенным маршрутам. При этом стоимость поездки составит 20 рублей — столько же, сколько в автобусе или троллейбусе городского маршрута. http://devyatka.ru/news/transport/476211/

А в **городе Долгопрудном** (Московская область) **в общественном такси** низкая стоимость проезда, а маршрут вроде бы индивидуальный. http://www.senao.org/obshhestvennoe-taksi-dolgoprudnogo-domchit-deshevo-i-s-veterkom/

Исходя их этого, можно сделать вывод о возможности **трех форм написания:**

1) ***общественное такси*** – нарицательное сочетание, когда термин понятен читателям или объясняется в статье;

2) ***"общественное такси"*** – нарицательное сочетание, когда термин неясен, требует пояснения, назван в статье первый раз; при повторном упоминании можно писать без кавычек;

3) имя собственное   городская служба ***"Общественное такси."***.

Comment: Забавно. Виктор Пинчук - автор статьи, приведенной в качестве примера - это я. http://gazetarespublika.info/proexat-aziyu-poezda-avtobusy-marshrutki/

Comment: http://time4news.org/content/nezabyvaemaya-petra  А здесь еще одна моя статья (10-я строка сверху), где корректор предпочел другой вариант.  В  Аммане,  столице  Иордании,  есть  такое  понятие — «общественное  такси».

Comment: Что ж, Виктор, приятно с Вами познакомиться. Интересно, нравится ли Вам наш форум. Что касается решения корректора, то в начале статьи  возможны, как я думаю, оба варианта, а затем можно кавычки уже не использовать.

Comment: Форум хороший, на большинство вопросов обстоятельно отвечают. Значит, кавычки оставляю. Может быть я неправильно назвал этот вид транспорта, но, по-моему, в РФ (Киров, Долгопрудный) не может быть общественного такси.

Comment: "Общественное такси"  в широком смысле - это такое такси, которое ближе к обычным общественным видам транспорта (по стоимости, по постоянству маршрута). В каждом городе может быть свое понимание этого термина.

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: В Аманне есть такая разновидность транспорта - общественное такси. Пояснительные члены предложения, стоящие в конце предложения, выделяются при помощи тире.

Comment: Нашел только что этот текст, отредактированный проф. редактором газеты: стоят кавычки и тире. Или кавычки, все-таки предпочтительнее убрать?

Comment: @Виктор Зависит от контекста. Если предполагается, что целевая аудитория (читатель) знает, что такое общественное такси, а новость в том, что оно есть в этом городе, тогда кавычки не нужны. Если же для читателя это будет новым и непривычным термином, лучше поставить кавычки.

Comment: @Виктор, кавычки лучше не ставить. У нас уже выражение общественный транспорт. Без кавычек.И здесь не нужны.

Comment: Так ставить или нет? Нужно объявить голосование. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Вот два примера из интернета:

> В Кирове Калужской области заработает общественное такси.
>   "Общественное такси" - новый формат транспорта

Если предполагается, что читателю термин не знаком, а вы хотите его ввести именно как термин, то ставьте тире и кавычки.

Comment: Не надо. Ср.: общетвенный транспорт - без кавычек.